# How to completely uninstall rails 3.0.0.beta3 and all its dependencies?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3

If I do `sudo gem uninstall rails -v 3.0.0.beta3`, it uninstalls rails but leaves the beta3 versions of activerecord, actionmailer, etc. How do I completely uninstall rails 3.0.0.beta3 and all its dependencies automatically? I would like a clean slate for the RC and final releases.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ gem list
...
$ sudo gem uninstall {gem-you-don't-want} {version-you-don't-want}
$ {rinse-and-repeat}
```

Comment: well sure, if you want to do it the hard way! i was hoping dependencies also worked for UNinstall :)

Comment: @Mark Richman: RubyGems doesn't track which gems were installed manually and which ones were installed automatically as dependencies. Therefore, it simply *cannot* know which ones are still needed.

Answer (score 1):

If your situation is that you have installed beta 4 and want to get rid of beta 3, you can simply run

```
gem cleanup
```

which removes all but the latest version of all your gems (wiping out beta 3 and leaving you with beta 4).

Answer (score 1):

You can list out all the dependencies of a specific rails version

```
$ gem dependency rails -v 3.1.0
Gem rails-3.1.0
  actionmailer (= 3.1.0)
  actionpack (= 3.1.0)
  activerecord (= 3.1.0)
  activeresource (= 3.1.0)
  activesupport (= 3.1.0)
  bundler (~> 1.0)
  railties (= 3.1.0)
```

Unfortunately there isn't any single command to remove all dependencies. You have to manually remove each dependent gem

$ gem remove activerecord  -v 3.1.0

```
You can also view reverse dependencies by using the **-v** flag

    $ gem dependency rails -r
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't do it automatically unless you write your own script wrapper around the gem uninstall command

just manually do gem uninstall on the other files like activerecord, activesupport, etc...

Answer (score 0):

you just try this command.it will help to uninstall all rails `gem uninstall railties` I think this is  only method to fully uninstall all version of rails